# jade doctype is rendering as text

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My jade file is as follows:

```
!!! 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title test page
  body
    h1 hello world
```

But it renders as:

```
!!! 5
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried just !!! as well as doctype - all render as text. Any ideas?

Comment: works fine for me with jade@0.27.7. what version are you using and on what OS? what encoding does your file have?

Comment: using 0.27.7 on windows. file is utf8.

Comment: check if your file has a BOM marker in the beginning

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, so the question doesn't remain open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your file has a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the beginning, if it does - remove it.

Some windows editors add it in order to distinguish endiannes.

Comment: someone set us up the bom?